# Divide a list into two, making sum of sublist equal

Tags: python

Assume there is a list `L=list(range(N))`, and number `n1` and `n2` where `n1+n2=sum(L)`.
I want to def an function to divide `L` into `L1` and `L2` so that `sum(L1)=n1` and `sum(L2)=n2`.

How to build this function in an effective way?

Example:

Given: N=7,n1=7,n2=14

We got: L=list(range(7))

We need `func(L)` returns [3,4] and [0,1,2,5,6]

Comment: Cn you show a toy example of the list and expacted output?

Comment: why it dose not returns [1,6] and [0,2,3,4,5] how it distributed?

Comment: @Ahmed Yousif Returning only one case that meet the requirement is enough.

Comment: It this homework?

Answer (score 2):

This will give you all the possible combinations that satisfy the criteria:

```
def fit_sum(l, s):
    for i, n in enumerate(l):
        if n == s:
            yield frozenset([n])
        elif n < s:
            for r in fit_sum(l[:i] + l[i+1:], s - n):
                yield frozenset([n, *r])

def func(N, n1, n2):
    L = list(range(N))
    for r in set(fit_sum(L, n1)):
        yield list(r), list(set(L) - r)

for L1, L2 in func(7, 7, 14):
    print('{}, {}'.format(L1, L2))
```

This outputs:

```
[0, 3, 4], [1, 2, 5, 6]
[3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 4], [0, 3, 5, 6]
[0, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4, 6]
[2, 5], [0, 1, 3, 4, 6]
[1, 6], [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 4], [3, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

@adam-smith's solution was correct, but had two litte errors.

Also, please note you should user lower case letters for
variables like lists.

```
def split_list(l, n1, n2):
    l1, l2 = [], []  # new lists
    x = max(n1, n2)
    for n in reversed(l):
        if n <= x:
            l1.append(n)
            x -= n
        else:
            l2.append(n)
    if n1 < n2:
        l2, l1 = l1, l2

    assert sum(l1) == n1, sum(l1)        
    assert sum(l2) == n2, sum(l2)
    return l1, l2
```

Comment: @Aran-fey Please mention the bug..It works for the test cases 7 & 8 for me.

Comment: @Aran-fey You're right... Thanks for pointing that out. Should work for both orders now...

Comment: It does indeed work now, but my downvote is staying because the code is really needlessly convoluted.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Don't worry about that. Thanks for replying and providing feedback.